# Magento2 : When edit data the data cannot be display?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

When edit the data cannot be display in form while using **ui-component** under edit tabs. And also the data save as empty.

Anyone know how to solve it? ``

sample_form.sample_form_data_source
        
        Sample Information
        true
    
    
        
            
            
            
            
            
        
        
            left
            tabs
        
        
            sample_form.sample_form_data_source
        
    
    
        
            
                Magento_Ui/js/form/provider
            
        
        
            
            
        
         
            
                id
                id
            
        
    

    
        
            Account Information
        
        
            
                
                    infromation
                
            
            
                text
                false
            
        
        
            
                
                    infromation
                
            
            
                text

            
        
        
            
                
                    infromation

``Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide more information for better understanding. @Raji

Comment: Can you please add code of your ui component form

Comment: i attached the  code.